# SubSonic 2.1 SqlQuery multiple Where()s?

Tags: subsonic, where-clause, sql

I'm building a SqlQuery to support an ad-hoc query screen.

I want something like this:

```
SqlQuery q = new Select().From<VwInstitutes>();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
{
    q.Where(VwInstitutes.Columns.AssignedUser).IsEqualTo(username); 
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stage))
{
    q.Where(VwInstitutes.Columns.Stage).IsEqualTo(stage); 
}
```

My problem is--attaching multiple Where()s doesn't seem to work--is that correct?

So now I'm writing this, but it's pretty ugly.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) 
{ 
    if (q.HasWhere) q.And(VwInstitutes.Columns.AssignedUser).IsEqualTo(username); 
    else q.Where(VwInstitutes.Columns.AssignedUser).IsEqualTo(username); 
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stage))
{
    if (q.HasWhere) q.And(VwInstitutes.Columns.Stage).IsEqualTo(stage); 
    else q.Where(VwInstitutes.Columns.Stage).IsEqualTo(stage);
}
```

Please tell me that there is a better idiom for this scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your query with a where that always evaluates to true.

```
new Select().From().Where("1").IsEqualTo("1");
```

then build the rest of the query with q.And. See [this thread](http://forums.subsonicproject.com/forums/t/4020.aspx) as well.

Comment: thanks ranomore. Yeah, I forgot that old sql trick. I think it's a little ugly too--in that it doesn't contribute to the semantics of the query--but it's LESS ugly than the way I was doing. Like the poster in the thread you linked to, I wonder what happened to AddWhere()....